# How to change the template text in maven pom.properties file?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

the starter text in pom.properties of any WAR produced by maven starts with like

```
#Generated by Maven

#Thu May 12 10:01:48 CST 2016
```

how can i remove these two lines in the file?

Comment: i am not sure how you can remove that, but does that change on changing the `archetype `?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developer here. The first comment is written by us, Maven Archiver, to identify that this file is autogenerated and not handcrafted. The second line is added by Sun's `Properties#store()` implementation. Have a look at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MSHARED-494.

Comment: wow, hello developer, nice to hear from you! So up to now there is no way to modify these lines or remove them? what a sad thing...

Comment: @ShedomWei, this is correct. Though, you can provide a patch for MSHARED-494 which will make the stuff way easier.

Comment: Hi, hello, one more quesiton: then why do we have to use Properties#store() method, rather than a self-create method? I think it's easy to write up as such method.

Comment: @ShedomWei One should try to avoid reinventing the wheel. For a simple line, no one's going to reimplement the entire store method for the properties spec.